# Upgraded motherboard and CPU; now no video output from GPU

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, motherboard, gpu

Previous set up was MSI B250 Gaming Pro motherboard with AMD RX 480 and Intel i5-7500 CPU. Replaced motherboard o with Asus Prime 660M-A D4 and CPU to i9-12900KF. Tried both 3.0 PCIe slots and get no video output from GPU now. Even swapped it out with another confirmed working RX 480 and get no video output when I boot the PC. Fans and lights power on as normal. No chirps or lights on the mmotherboard.

What could be a potential source for this problem assuming I did not bend a pin or screw something up?

Comment: You may have damaged something replacing parts - retrace your steps.  Also update BIOS.

Comment: check BIOS setup for any gpu priority setting